# What is the right way to read part of content from a file?

Tags: c#

I want to read some part of the content from a text file which has got the following content with line breaks:

```
Content-Type: multipart/signed;
    boundary="boundarytext"

--<boundarytext>
Content-Type: text/plain

{1:A}{2:B      N}{4:
:10:C123
:11:124
:43E:
test.txt
2010-03-20/09:37:45
Accepted
-}
--<boundarytext>
```

I am expecting the following:

```
{1:A}{2:B      N}{4:
:10:C123
:11:124
:43E:
test.txt
2010-03-20/09:37:45
Accepted
-}
```

Currently trying to read the file line by line.

Is there any best approach to achieve my expected result?

Here is the code i am using,

```
    using (var fileRead = new StreamReader(@"c:\temp\testfile.txt"))
    {
        var blockIdentifier = "{1:";
        var textBlockIdentifier = "-}";
        var fileContent = fileRead.ReadToEnd();
        var startPos = fileContent.LastIndexOf(blockIdentifier);
        var length = (fileContent.IndexOf(textBlockIdentifier) + 2) - startPos;
        var newContent = fileContent.Substring(startPos, length);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: "best approach" -> Use a library designed to parse multipart email messages, as that appears to be what you have?  That will deal with changing boundary identifiers, differing headers per block etc.

Comment: It's hard to help without any code, although in general the answer is no - files have offsets, not lines, so in order to read line 5, you have to read the previous 4 lines. But if this text is the response to an HTTP call, you may not need to do that at all, you only need to decode the content

Comment: Concurring with @JamesThorpe: Look into https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. It may have what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use LINQ:

```
string[] relevantLines = File.ReadLines(path)
    .SkipWhile(l => !l.StartsWith("--<boundarytext>"))
    .Skip(3)
    .TakeWhile(l => !l.StartsWith("--<boundarytext>"))
    .ToArray();
```

It seems that the `boundarytext` always changes, so you need to detect it first:

```
string boundaryTextLine = File.ReadLines(path)
  .FirstOrDefault(l => l.IndexOf("boundary=", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
if(boundaryTextLine != null)
{
    string boundaryText = boundaryTextLine
        .Substring(boundaryTextLine.IndexOf("boundary=", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) + "boundary=".Length)
        .Trim(' ', '"');
}
```

Comment: That *will* read the lines, which is what the OP seems to want to avoid. Although it would be better to process the multipart email with a library instead of trying to do that by hand. There may be a relevant library already in the BCL itself

Comment: What if `boundarytext` changes? This code only works for this exact situation.

Comment: boundarytext always changes

Comment: @MukilDeepthi: i've edited my answer to show how to detect the boundarytext first.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use a regex

`/(?<=\-\-<boundarytext>)\n(.+)\n(?=\-\-<boundarytext>)/gsU`

See: https://regex101.com/r/rB1tC8/1

I would even parse the content_type from the message. For your conveiniance, here is a working test case for c#

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var input = @"Content-Type: multipart/signed;
    boundary='boundarytext1'

--<boundarytext1>
Content-Type: text/plain

{1:A}{2:B      N}{4:
:10:C123
:11:124
:43E:
test.txt
2010-03-20/09:37:45
Accepted
-}
--<boundarytext1>

Content-Type: multipart/signed;
    boundary='boundarytext2'

--<boundarytext2>
Content-Type: text/plain

{1:A}{2:B      N}{4:
:10:C123
:11:124
:43E:
test.txt
2010-03-20/09:37:45
Accepted
-}
--<boundarytext2>".Replace("'", "\"");

            var pattern = @"

boundary='(.+)'         # capture the boundary delimiter in \1
.+
(--<\1>)                # every message starts with --<boundary>
.+
Content-Type:\s
(?<content_type>[\w/]+) # capture the content_type
(\r?\n)+
(?<content>.+?)         # capture the content
(\r?\n)+
(--<\1>)                # every message ends with --<boundary>

".Replace("'", "\"");
            var regex = new Regex(pattern, 
                RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
            var matches = regex.Matches(input);
            Assert.AreEqual(2, matches.Count);
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                var content_type = match.Groups["content_type"].Value;
                var content = match.Groups["content"].Value;
                Assert.AreEqual("text/plain", content_type);
                Assert.IsTrue(content.StartsWith("{1") && content.EndsWith("-}"));
            }
        }
    }
```